# I want to delete all groups with "zero" members the following codes picks 1st one and delete it

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

[enter image description here][1]```

def select_delete_group(self):
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
expected_conditions.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "user-info")))
users = self.driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "user-info")
for members in users:
m = members.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "a")
time.sleep(10)

```
    if '0 members' in m.text.strip():
        m.click()
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
            expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, self.delete_group_xpath))).click()
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
            expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, self.ok_button_xpath))).click()
```

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eA9us.png)
Now I want to run the same code until no further "0 members" found


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IM7lr.png
```

Comment: indentation is important in python. Fix the indentation on time.sleep and if statement.

Comment: i would suggest posting an example how that element looks like (HTML, XML). Also did you check if the users list is correct (the count is what you expect). You could be doing a for loop for just one located element.

Comment: <img class="img-circle" ng-src="/static/images/staff-group.png" alt="Click to view Fancy Group 1's profile" src="/static/images/staff-group.png">
  </div><!-- end ngIf: ::staff.type=='group' -->

  <!-- ngIf: ::staff.type=='group' --><div class="advisee-basic" ng-if="::staff.type=='group'">
    <a ui-sref="mn.staff.overview({id: staff.id})" href="/app/staffprofile/overview?id=32">
      <h2 class="body-large color-gray100">Fancy Group 1 </h2>
      0 members

Answer (score -1):

You need to do the if in a loop. Currently, you are only asking if there is any row with 0 members in the text. So something like:

```
> For x in m.text.strip:
> 
>     if x == '0 members':
> 
>         #do stuff
```

Comment: he clearly has a loop but the for cycle indentation is wrong.

Comment: Ok, actually my indention is alligned in the actual code it got disturbed while pasting here and this code,as soon as it finds the first group with 0 members in it deletes it what I want is to delete each and every group one by one and I want this code to repeat itself until the condition of 0 members is False

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).